# How to install and use package in umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-blog

I am developing project into umbraco cms can anyone suggest me procedure of packages in umbraco, how to install and use packages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco packages is a way to transfer Umbraco nodes (content) and/or functionality between Umbraco installations. Inside the Developer section, under Packages, try right clicking "Created packages" and choose "Create". There you can see all the things that can be in a package - document types, templates, views, stylesheets, media files and so on.

Here's how to install packages:

https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/packages-and-projects/how-to-install-a-package

And here's where you can typically find packages if they're not in the Umbraco Package Repository:

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio for developing Umbraco websites, I strongly suggest installing [Umbraco itself](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms/) as well as Umbraco packages via the NuGet package manager. It is far easier to maintain your website in terms of upgrading to newer versions and you also don't have to leave your IDE.

[image]

Unfortunatelly, not all packages offer this option, but I recommend either doing a search using the package installer in Visual studio or checking the [Umbraco project](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/) page to find out if the one you've decided to use offers this option (hint: check out the *External Resources* section).

If your package however doesn't offer this option, your only choice is to use the Umbraco backoffice. All you have to do is navigate to the ***Developer*** section and select ***Packages***. You then either have the option of using the package repository, or installing the package from a locally downloaded .zip file

[image]

Comment: Does the `nuget` method update the umbraco backoffice? Do I have to do anything additional to synchronize the installed packages across environments?

Comment: @Kunal, yes it does, the `nuget` package installation will usually copy any necessary files to the `App_Plugins` folder as well as the `bin` folder. All you need to do is ensure those files get deployed to other environments.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using NuGet to install packages. 
For example, if you need to install UmbracoCMS, just open Nuget Console and type install-package umbracocms

Hope that helps.